# Is this a valid way to provide STL functions in a library regardless of CRT version?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, stl, crt

I am trying to migrate some static C++ libraries into DLLs with a C interface so I don't need to build a separate version of the library for every version of Visual Studio (i.e. CRT) we want to support. However, I do like the convenience of using STL objects for some of the function calls. I came up with something that seems to work, but was wondering if there may be some hidden things that I'm just not thinking of.

Here is what I came up with to get STL versions of functions while still maintaining Visual Studio independence.

Original library function:

```
//library.h
...
std::wstring GetSomeString();
...
StringGenerator* mStrGen; //assume forward declared for pimpl implementation

//library.cpp
std::wstring library::GetSomeString()
{
  return mStrGen->GetString(); //returns a wstring;
}
```

First, I created a private function that would provide the C interface

```
//library.h
__declspec(dllexport) void GetSomeStringInternal(wchar_t* pSomeString);

//library.cpp
void library::GetSomeString(wchar_t*& pSomeString)
{
    if(pSomeString!= nullptr) {
        delete [] pSomeString; //assumes allocated by the DLL
    }

    std::wstring tmpString(mStrGen->GetString());

    size_t stringLength(tmpString.size());

    stringToReturn = new wchar_t[stringLength + 1];

    wcscpy_s(pSomeString, stringLength + 1, tmpString.c_str());
}
```

Next, I added a private function that deallocates memory allocated by the DLL

```
//library.h
__declspec(dllexport) void FreeArray(void* arrayPtr);

//library.cpp
void library::FreeArray(void* arrayPtr)
{
 if(arrayPtr) {
   delete [] arrayPtr; 
  }
}
```

Finally, I converted the original C++ function returning a string into a function that calls the internal C interface function

```
//library.h

std::wstring GetSomeString()
{
  std::wstring someString(L"");
  wchar_t* pSomeString= NULL;

  GetSomeStringInternal(pSomeString);
  someString = pSomeString;

  FreeArray(pSomeString);
  return someString;
}

//library.cpp
//removed GetSomeString from cpp since it is defined in header
```

My thinking is that since the header will be compiled every time it is included, an application that uses a different version of the CRT will compile the function using its implementation of the CRT. All data passed into and out of the library uses a C interface to preserve compatibility and memory is allocated and freed by the library so you don't run into one version of the CRT trying to free memory from a different version.

It seems to perform as I intend:

- The library can be used by programs compiled with multiple versions of Visual Studio.
- There are no memory leaks or access violations
- If I modify the code so that memory is allocated in the GetSomeString function in the header, I do get a memory access error when trying to free that memory.
- The GetSomeString function is compiled by the library and included in the DLL, but it is never called since it is 1) not exported and 2) the compiling program will always choose its version since it is inlined.

Is there anything I am missing, or is this a valid way of going about providing a C++ interface to a library that is Visual Studio version independent?

Side note: I have run into some deletion issues if I have a program that uses a `std::shared_ptr<library>`, but haven't researched that issue enough and will probably have a follow up question on that problem.

Comment: So you've basically written a C interface for the cross DLL calls, then written a C++ interface that calls it?  Seems fine to me.  You'll probably have to use a custom deleter on the shared_ptr to get that to work.

Comment: The odd thing was a custom deleter didn't work. I added static library* CreateLibrary() and DeleteLibrary(library*) functions to allocate and deallocate in the DLL, but the shared_ptr still gave a memory exception.

Comment: Looks an awful lot like you're reinventing COM.  COM is actually a pretty good solution to the problem you're actually trying to solve (providing object oriented componentry with a stable, Visual Studio version independent API).  Unfortunately COM seems to be deeply unfashionable these days (and STL interop was never good) but maybe WinRT will be a renaissance for it (and I've seen some material at least showing interop between WinRT collections and STL).

Answer (score 2):

One thing I could see becoming a problem is if you actually needed to pass large objects around by reference for performance reasons.  You're dealing with the binary compatibility issues by copying all the data to and from a compatible format, which is fine until it becomes a performance issue.